# Undefined when the first time render() works

Tags: react-native

In my react native app, I have the following code.

```
  render() {
    return (
      <Swiper height={height} showsButtons={true} showsPagination={false}>    
        this.props.features.forEach(feature => {
          <SwiperSlider imageSource={feature.featureImage} />
        });
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
```

This give me the error, "FEATURE IS NOT DEFINED".
When the render() runs for the first time, features array is empty. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `map` and enclose it with curly braces.

```
  <Swiper height={height} showsButtons showsPagination={false}>
    {this.props.features.map((feature) => <SwiperSlider imageSource={feature.featureImage} />)}
  </Swiper>
```